# How to identify iphone , ipad ,ipod touch, iphpne simulator while programming in 3.2 version?

Tags: iphone

Am unable to identify the device models (iphone , ipad ,ipod touch, iphpne simulator) while programming (in 3.2 version). Alreay am tried with UIDevice Class and some other means, but am unable to get model as ipad when connected to ipad. every time it is giving model other than ipad. So can any one please help me out. Thank you.

Comment: A piece of code showing how you try to obtain the model might help. Also if you are actually running on a physical iPad of from the simulator.

Comment: Have you used `[UIDevice model]`?

Answer (score 1):

I've used this code and it works really well:

```
size_t size;  
sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);  
char *machine = malloc(size);  
sysctlbyname("hw.machine", machine, &size, NULL, 0);  
NSString *platform = [NSString stringWithCString:machine];  
free(machine);  
return platform;
```

This come from [arstechnica.com](http://arstechnica.com/apple/guides/2009/03/iphone-dev-determining-your-platform.ars).

Comment: Yes but IMHO this is not part of the public API, so you may run into trouble with new iPhoneOS versions or worst, you could get your app rejected.

Comment: Unfortunately you could be right... I've used it in an app that is right now on sale in App Store, the real problem could be only with future iPhoneOS version..

Answer (score 0):

The general approach is to avoid trying to guess device models by yourself. In most of the cases (but you didn't described your original need), the framework provides you the HW capabilities from the API and you don't really have to know which models you're using in reality.

For instance, if you want to know if a camera is available, you're not going to check in your code  `if (model==iphone3G || model==iPhone3Gs)`

You're just going to ask something like `[UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]` that is part of the public API.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to check [UIDevice userInterfaceIdiom]. On either the iPad or the iPad sim this will return UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad. On other devices or sims it will return UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone.